# Docker - error after moved storage to second disk and using overlay2

Tags: docker, configuration

I just moved Docker default storage location to second disk setting up a `/etc/docker/daemon.json` as described in [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/), so far so goood.

The problem is that now I keep getting a bunch of volumes being continuously (re)mounted, ad obiously it is really annoying.

[image]

So I tried to set up `overlay2` in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`, but now Docker doesn't event start

```
# sudo systemctl restart docker
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xeu docker.service" for details.
```

```
# systemctl status docker.service
× docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2022-12-15 11:06:36 CET; 10s ago
TriggeredBy: × docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
    Process: 17614 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock (code=exited, status>
   Main PID: 17614 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 54ms

dic 15 11:06:36 sgratani-OptiPlex-7060 systemd[1]: docker.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
dic 15 11:06:36 sgratani-OptiPlex-7060 systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
dic 15 11:06:36 sgratani-OptiPlex-7060 systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
dic 15 11:06:36 sgratani-OptiPlex-7060 systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
dic 15 11:06:36 sgratani-OptiPlex-7060 systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
```

So, for now I give up using `overlay2` since having all the Docker images and container on the seond disk is more important than getting rid of a bunch of volumes being mounted continuously, but can anyone tells me where the problem is and if there is a solution?

##### Update #1: strange permissions behaviour problem

Got a simple `docker-compose.yml` with a Wordpress service (official WP image) and a database service, and when I have the docker storage location on the second disk instead of default one the database (volume maybe?) seems inaccessible:

- wordpress keep giving error on db connection
- trying to run mysql interactive from db service result in error on login with root user

Obviously this is related to the docker storage location, but cannot find why, since new location is created by docker itself when started.